# WCF MIME message from embedded device is "Malformed" - why?

Tags: .net, wcf, mime, malformed

I am running a WCF Service on Windows 10 using IIS Express. I am sending messages from an embedded devices and forming the POST request and XML by hand in the embedded code. I have been able to send a simple "single part" message and get a successful response.

Now, I am trying to send a MIME multipart message. I was able to successfully do this with a Windows client, and I used Wireshark to capture the message text. I am trying to send the same text from the embedded device. It seems like this should work, however the server returns an error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 14 Feb 2016 01:45:36 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

I am able to enable WCF tracing and determine the cause is the message being considered "Malformed", as shown in the following message log record:

```
<MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2016-02-13T19:45:36.7215337-06:00" Source="Malformed" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace"><![CDATA[--uuid:34450500-f156-44c4-9029-39b25c2794d5+id=2
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IService1/StoreData</a:Action><a:MessageID>urn:uuid:c6cb5104-adfd-4040-a2eb-a2cb659e8f2a</a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://192.168.0.10:8080/Service1.svc</a:To></s:Header><s:Body><StoreData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><device>22222</device><time>2016-01-10T14:34:54.2151851-06:00</time><data>AwIB</data></StoreData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:34450500-f156-44c4-9029-39b25c2794d5+id=2--]]></MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

I dug in further and found the following stack trace in the svclog:

```
<Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Error creating a reader for the MTOM message</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageData.GetMessageReader()
at ...
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.FormatException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Unexpected end of file.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Xml.MimeReader.ReadNextPart()
at System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.ReadMimePart(String uri)
at ...
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.MtomBufferedMessageData.TakeXmlReader()</ExceptionString></InnerException></Exception>
```

The text **Unexpected end of file** error stood out, so I thought maybe my length was not set correctly. It is computed, but I tried adding many extra \n with no help.

One thing I am not sure about is what type of line ends are expected. I assume only 0xA (LF) and not 0xD (CR), but I wonder if line ends are causing the count to be incorrect.

Any ideas for why this message is being rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem has to do with line endings. The Windows WCF server expects CR+LF at the end of every line. My embedded client was only sending LF. Unfortunately, this is not obvious in the message dumps or the error messages. Compare the Wireshark **binary** capture to see the difference.

Comment: A MIME/MTOM message validator for SOAP sure would have been handy, but I could not find one. I anyone aware of any?